# Image Id does not exists in current context asp.net 

Tags: javascript, .net

I am getting following error for this code .
I am using repeater for displaying the images . the image id is img .in jquery i am using `$("#<%=img.ClientID %>")` for getting image. But its giving error like , img does not exists in current context. The repeater id is `rptRepeater`.
How can I solve this problem ? `$("#<%=img.ClientID %>") doesnot exists in current context`

**.NET Code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterView" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <a onmouseout="SelectEnd()" onmouseover='<%#Eval("Coords","preview(\"{0}\");")%>'>     
            <asp:Image ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> ' Height="150" Width="150" >    
            </asp:Image> 
        </a> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function preview(Coords) { 
        var arrResult = Coords.split(","); 
        var nx1 = arrResult[0]; 
        var ny1 = arrResult[1]; 
        var nx2 = arrResult[2]; 
        var ny2 = arrResult[3]; 
        var ias = $("#<%=ImageZoom.ClientID %>").imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
        ias.setSelection(nx1, ny1, nx2, ny2, true); ias.setOptions({ show: true });     
        ias.update(); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are missing half your post.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterView" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<a onmouseout="SelectEnd()" onmouseover='<%#Eval("Coords","preview(\"{0}\");")%>'>
<asp:Image ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> ' Height="150" Width="150" >
     

    </asp:Image>
</a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Comment: Why did you add it as a comment and not in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have is there is no one id for that, you are adding multiple elements to the page so it would be impossible for that code to handle all of the elements. You need to make it more generic.

Try and change your code to this which needs no ids.

**.NET Code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterView" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <a onmouseout="SelectEnd()" onmouseover='<%#Eval("Coords","preview(this, \"{0}\");")%>'>     
            <asp:Image ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> ' Height="150" Width="150" >    
            </asp:Image> 
        </a> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function preview(elem, Coords) { 
        var arrResult = Coords.split(","); 
        var nx1 = arrResult[0]; 
        var ny1 = arrResult[1]; 
        var nx2 = arrResult[2]; 
        var ny2 = arrResult[3]; 
        var ias = $(elem).find("img").imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
        ias.setSelection(nx1, ny1, nx2, ny2, true); ias.setOptions({ show: true });     
        ias.update(); 
    }
</script>
```